# Handle click events

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a toggle that focuses an input when I click the button and blurs it when I click outside the input or a second time at the button.

My only problem is when I click outside the input I need to click two times on the button to focus the input again.

My function

```
let isFocused = false
const blurAlias = () => {
  document.getElementById('aliasInput').blur()
  document.getElementById('aliasInput').setAttribute("disabled", true);
}
const focusAlias = () => {
  isFocused = !isFocused

   if ( document.activeElement === document.getElementById('aliasButton')) {
      document.getElementById('aliasInput').removeAttribute("disabled")
      document.getElementById('aliasInput').focus();
      document.getElementById('aliasInput')
      .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        blurAlias()
        }
    });
    }
  }
```

My HTML:

```
<input disabled class="break-word mb-0 editAliasInput" 
       data-ng-value="ext.helpers.handleAlias($ctrl.state.accounts.accountDetails)" 
       id="aliasInput" maxlength="35" 
       onkeypress="this.style.minWidth = ((this.value.length + 1) * 12) + 'px'"
       onblur="setAttribute('disabled', true)">
<button class="editAliasButton" ng-click="ext.helpers.focusAlias()" 
        id="aliasButton"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Mixing DOM event handlers and AngularJS event handlers like this is asking for trouble. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: @georgeawg you're right. I solved it just using event handlers. Thank you for the help